# I want to read from a file and scrape each URL

Tags: python, scrapy

What I want to do is read every URL from a file and scrape this URL. After that, I will move the scraping data to the class `WebRealTor` and then serialize data in json and finally save all the data in a json file.
This is the content of the file:
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/paris-14eme-75/montsouris-dareau/143580615.htm?ci=750114&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=2,1&LISTING-LISTpg=8&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montpellier-34/gambetta/137987697.htm?ci=340172&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=1,2&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montpellier-34/celleneuve/142626025.htm?ci=340172&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=1,2&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/versailles-78/domaine-national-du-chateau/138291887.htm

And my script is:

```
import scrapy
import json



class selogerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "realtor"

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
            'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    }
}

    def start_requests(self):
         with open("annonces.txt", "r") as file:
             for line in file.readlines():
                  yield scrapy.Request(line)
    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.css(".agence-link::text").extract_first()
        address = response.css(".agence-adresse::text").extract_first()

        XPATH_siren = ".//div[@class='legalNoticeAgency']//p/text()"
        siren = response.xpath(XPATH_siren).extract_first()

        XPATH_website = ".//div[@class='agence-links']//a/@href"
        site = response.xpath(XPATH_website).extract()

        XPATH_phone = ".//div[@class='contact g-row-50']//div[@class='g-col g-50 u-pad-0']//button[@class='btn-phone b-btn b-second fi fi-phone tagClick']/@data-phone"
        phone = response.xpath(XPATH_phone).extract_first()


        yield {
            'Agency_Name =': name,
            'Agency_Address =': address,
            'Agency_profile_website =': site,
            'Agency_number =': phone,
            'Agency_siren =': siren
        }

        file.close()


class WebRealTor:

    def __name__(self):
        self.nom = selogerSpider.name
    def __address__(self):
        self.adress = selogerSpider.address
    def __sirenn__(self):
        self.sire = selogerSpider.siren
    def __numero__(self):
        self.numero = selogerSpider.phone


with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Be aware that this website do not authorize scrapping :). However what is your problem exactly? What does not work?

Comment: okay what i want it mooving the scraping data to the webRealTor class and then saving it in a json file

Comment: open file ---> scrape data ---> class webrealtor ---> serialize data in json ----> saving data in a json file

Comment: Then you have nearly your code, this is kinda straightforward. Use `readlines` then for each line, use your custom method which returns data `extract_data`, then add them to your class, then create a dict and then save it to a json file I do not get where you are stuck

Comment: @BlueSheepToken the problem that im a beginner in python so i need a help with editing my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move everything to `start_requests` in you class. Like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open("annonces.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            yield scrapy.Request(line)  # self.parse is by default

def parse(self, response):
    # each link parsing as you already did
```

Comment: and then how he will scrape each line?

Comment: You have links in your file. This will make requests to each link in your file. Can you detail your question?

Comment: when i put this code he underline Request with a red line

Comment: okay and after that i want to move the data to webrealtor class and then save it in a json file

Comment: @joes Have a look at using Scrapy's [Item](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) for your data class. To export a JSON file you can use a [Feed exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html). Here is a simple [export example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data)

Comment: @joes In that case, use an [Item Exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html)

Comment: the problem that im a beginner in python so i need a help with editing my code

Comment: @malberts this is what i want to dot

Comment: open file ---> scrape data ---> class webrealtor ---> serialize data in json ----> saving data in a json file